# foreach not applicable to type

Tags: java, list, loops

I am trying to store the dog and fish object into the LinkedList, why is my enhanced for loop not working?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimalList animal = new AnimalList();
        Animal dog = new Dog();
        Animal fish = new Fish();

        animal.add(dog);
        animal.add(fish);
    }
}

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class AnimalList {
    private List<Animal> theList = new LinkedList<>();

    public void add(Animal animal) {
        for (Animal x: animal) {  <--------- foreach not applicable to type.
            theList.add(x);
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}

public class Animal {
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
}

public class Fish extends Animal {
}
```

Comment: Hint: `animal` in the `main` and `animal` in the `add` are two different animals.

Comment: "For each animal in an animal" doesn't make much sense. What's the for-loop supposed to do anyway? I don't see any reason to loop over anything. Do you know what a for-loop does?

Comment: I was thinking that the for each animal is the animal objects (dog and fish) that I would be creating (have not done in this code), and I would store these objects into the linked list. Does this make sense?

Comment: That makes some sense, but that's not how code works. Your add method takes a single animal and adds it to the list, the fact that you want to call that method multiple times doesn't change what it's supposed to do for one single call.

Comment: Shouldn't you do AnimalList.add(dog) instead of animal.add(dog) ?

Comment: @JSmith That would only work if `add` were `static`. `animal.add(dog)` is fine logic-wise, but `animal` should probably have a different name (`animals` and `animalList` would be good candidates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have made a number of simple mistakes here.  And (to my mind) the common thread that links these mistakes is not having a clear idea of the purpose of the classes you are creating.

For example, your `Animal` class represents a single beast ... not a collection of beasts.  You do not "add" an animal to another animal, an animal doesn't contain other animals<sup>1</sup>.   Neither of these things make sense in the simple "world model" you have developed.

Yet, you have written:

```
    animal.add(dog);
    animal.add(fish);
```

and this:

```
    for (Animal x: animal)
```

Now the compiler can see<sup>2</sup> that *something* is wrong:

- It knows that there is no `add(Animal)` method declared for the `Animal` class
- It knows that `Animal` does not implement `Iterable<Animal>` ... which would be the way to iterate the animals that an animal contained.

But what the compiler cannot do is to understand the thought processes that caused you to make these mistakes.  It cannot say to you: "It doesn't make sense for animals to contain animals!".

Thinking about and understanding the task that you are trying to perform is your job.  This is why people and not computers are employed as programmers ....

---

Here's what you should do.  Look at each line of your code and ask yourself.

1. What is this telling the program to do?
2. Does it actually make sense to do that?

and when you have recovered from "face palming", correct the errors.

---

<sup>1 - Unless it is a python after a good meal.</sup>

<sup>2 - I am using "see", "know" and "understand" here in a metaphorical sense.  The compiler is not capable of thought or understanding.  It is simply applying a set of rules that determine if the program as written is valid Java code.  But that's really the point I am trying to make here.</sup>